# javascript object literal, value/no value?

Tags: javascript, console, object-literal

I am using

```
console.log(p);
console.log(p.datestrshow);
```

However the output in the console is

[image: console output]

Why is it undefined when it is clearly not?

---

doing

```
for(i in p)
  console.log(i+': ', (typeof p[i] == 'function' ? 'function' : p[i]));
```

results in [image]

Comment: doing e.g. `console.log(p.method)` returns 'POST'. which is why I am so confused

Comment: does it make a difference if you use `p['datestrshow']` ?

Comment: what about `String(p.datestrshow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log` doesn't make a clone of your `p` object when you call it.

What's happening is that `p.datestrshow` is indeed undefined when you `console.log`, but by the time you expand the `p` object in the console, it has been defined, and the console is showing the current state of the `p` object with `datestrshow` defined.

Here's a test you can do in the console:

```
var test = {a:'a'};
console.log( test );  // log to the console before we define 'b'
test.b = 'b';
```

Run this code in the console, then expand the object that was logged. Even though we clearly defined `b` after the `console.log`, it still shows up when you expand the object.

Comment: but how could it be defined within the execution of those two lines?

Comment: if it helps I am using http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/

Comment: I am trying to fix the fact that in the demo (http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php) the date picker date does not change from `loading` untill it is click the first time...

Comment: @Hailwood: It isn't. It is defined later, but the display of the `p` object in the console is *not* a snapshot of a point in time. When `console.log(p.datestrshow);` runs, it is indeed undefined. But by the time you physically expand the object in the console, it has been defined and the console reflects the current state of `p` with the `datestrshow`.

Comment: @Hailwood: Sorry, but I won't be much help with that plugin. I can only explain why that property shows up as undefined when accessed directly, but defined from the object reference. You may want to start another question with your plugin issue.